# Is this a right way to use husky + lint-staged?

Tags: husky, lint-staged

I found numerous blogs (including the lint-staged doc) introducing such a way to use husky+ lint-staged as the following code defined in the package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.js": ["prettier --write","eslint --fix", "git add"]
  }
}
```

Since there are errors that neither "prettier" nor "eslint --fix" can fix, how can we prevent bad commit by such a usage?

Answer (score 28):

You can indeed run multiple commands with lint-staged and if one of them fails, you will get the correct exit code as shown in the example below. This works via the new [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) hooks system:

With a configuration like this in `package.json`:

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    },
},
"lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css}": [
        "prettier --write",
        "eslint --fix src/",
        "tslint --fix --project .",
        "git add"
    ]
},
```

The configuration runs `prettier, eslint and tslint` - you would get the following error on linting problems:

```
husky > pre-commit (node v8.12.0)
  ↓ Stashing changes... [skipped]
    → No partially staged files found...
  ❯ Running linters...
   ❯ Running tasks for src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css}
      ✖ prettier --write
        eslint --fix src/
        tslint --fix --project .
        git add
✖ prettier --write found some errors. Please fix them and try committing again.
...
husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

The last line shows you that git's own `pre-commit` hook failed and thus your changed won't get commited (if they are not fixable).

Comment: Your are missing a closing bracket for your husky entry ;)

Comment: you don't need `git add` if you use lint-staged >= 10.0.0 (see here https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged/releases/tag/v10.0.0)

Comment: Also, `tslint` is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

Some files I use, in case someone can be interested:

**.prettierrc**

```
{
  "printWidth": 120,
  "proseWrap": "preserve",
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "useTabs": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "trailingComma": "es5"
}
```

**.lintstagedrc**

```
{
  "**/*.+(js|md)": [
    "prettier --write",
    "eslint --fix src/",
    "git add"
  ]
}
```

**.prettierignore**

```
node_modules
coverage
```

**.huskyrc**

```
{
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

##### Configure husky, lint-staged

Install following packages to run pre-commit hooks before commit

```
 npm install -D eslint prettier stylelint
```

- Updated package.json

```json
 "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "stylelint": "^13.13.1"
  }
```

This command will install and configure husky and lint-staged for following packages installed

```
 npx mrm@2 lint-staged
```

- **"lint-staged"** property is added and following packages are added to devDependencies in package.json
- This command will also add **'.husky'** folder that will contain **pre-commit** hook

```json
 "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": "eslint --cache --fix",
    "*.css": "stylelint --fix",
    "*.{js,css,md}": "prettier --write"
  }

 "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "husky": ">=6",
    "lint-staged": ">=10",
    ...
  }

  "scripts": {
    ...
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
```

##### Configuration files

- Stylelint configuration file -> **.stylelintrc**

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    <CAN_HAVE_PLUGINS> LIKE ("stylelint-order","stylelint-scss") AND FOLLOWING PROPERTIES OVERRIDDEN IN "rules {...}"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "indentation": 2,
    "unit-allowed-list": [
      "em",
      "rem",
      "px",
      "%"
    ],
    "order/properties-order": [
      [
        "width",
        "height"
      ],
    "order/properties-alphabetical-order": null,
    "unit-case": "lower",
    "property-case": "lower",
    "string-quotes": "single"
  }
}
```

- Prettier configuration file -> **.prettierrc**

```js
{
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "printWidth": 120,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "useTabs": true,
    "semi": false
}
```

- Eslint configuration file -> **"eslintrc.json"**

```json
{
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended"],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": [
      <PLUGINS>
  ],
  "rules": {
  ...
   "no-delete-var": "error",
    "no-dupe-args": "error",
    "no-dupe-class-members": "error",
    "no-dupe-keys": "error",
    "no-duplicate-case": "error",
    ...
    <MORE_RULES_DEFINED>
  },
  "env": {
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true
  },
}
```

- You can have also ignored files to ignore following files/dir from linting

```
- .prettierignore
- .stylelintignore
- .eslintignore
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a good practice is a little bigger than just these tools.
I would leverage having an `.editorconfig`, ( Not everyone uses the same IDE/Editor ) in combination with a good `eslint` setup, and testing, and a formatting script. You will need to do this twice, once in a hook setup via husky.. and once in CI. ( CI will catch folks who try to --no-verify over a hook )

Run `npm install --save-dev husky lint-staged` and create a `.lintstagedrc` and as well as an `.huskyrc` at root.

Example setup for some scripts in `package.json`

**package.json**

In this example I have lint, prettier, and a format script. And notice I am ignoring files in my .gitignore for formatting.

```
   "format": "npm run pretty -- --write",
    "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --ext .js --ext .jsx .",
    "pretty": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore \"**/*.+(js|json|md)\"",
```

**.lintstagedrc**

This will run the commands I want to run when lint-staged is called from the husky hook. If you want to add --fix to the eslint command you can append it here. Be sure your prettier tool is setup to handle formatting afterward.

```
{
  "*.+(js|jsx)":[
    "eslint"
  ],
  "*.+(js|json|md)":[
    "prettier --write"
  ]
}
```

**.huskyrc**

Obviously you can extend a ton of scripts in the pre-commit, pre-push or other hooks via husky.. even enforce commit messages.

```
{
  "hooks":{
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged && npm run test",
    "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can't do that with regular linting either. This will not give you a solution, but it will point out any potential errors in your code.