# Getting used to regular expressions in TS

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, typescript, package.json

I would like to lint staged files that are both .ts or .tsx that are inside the src folder, I know that in order to select all js files you can do "*.js": [--list of commands--] inisde the lint staged property.

I would like to know more about this language used select and import files in node.js, is it similar to regex without escape characters or is it Unix based?

Answer (score 2):

Those are [GLOB patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))

Most of the time you'll see simple wildcard patterns like:

```
*.ts
```

Matches:

```
foo.ts
bar.baz.ts
```

Or you'll need to match all files in a directory no matter how deeply nested:

```
src/**/*.ts
```

Matches:

```
src/foo.ts
src/bar/baz.ts
src/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i.ts
```

Comment: Any chance I could use a pattern to match the .tsx files inside the src folder? Or should I duplicate the commands?

Comment: I'm not sure what are asking that isn't outlined above. ".tsx files inside the src folder" would be either `src/*.tsx` for all files in that folder or `src/**/*.tsx` for all files nested under that folder.

Comment: I found what I was looking right here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53670956/12898885, thanks